# CSS query selector to select itself

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to select itself when using querySelector. For example: Let's say I have and HTML element A. I want to select if self A, when I query like this: `A.querySelector();`

Comment: If you have `A`, `A` is already itself

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you looking for [:is](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/new-css-is-for-easy-element-targeting--cms-34223?utm_source=Iterable&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=the_overflow_newsletter&utm_content=12-11-19)?